# Drupal 8: Why I get an error after adding a .theme file?

Tags: php, drupal, opcache

After creating .theme file in my template folder (whether empty or not), I get the following error message:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/homepages/d825952918/htdocs/themes/universaldenker/universaldenker.theme" at line 1. in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start() (line 145 of vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php).
```

If I delete .theme file again, everything works again. I think it has something to do with opcache, because the path "/homepages/d825952918/htdocs/themes/universaldenker/universaldenker.theme" comes from the .opcache folder.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post what code is in theme file here. The error is saying that another file / code send request back that you’re attempting to send it.

Comment: Maybe you have output of some sort in your .theme file? Like the new line before opening <?php ?